# How to force stash pop to overwrite or avoid conflicts?

Tags: git

I come across this situation every now and then that after pulling the code  from a remote branch I need to edit the all API calls to point to my local server. So to overcome this (somewhat), I stash these changes just before pulling the code and then pop the stash and work my way through the conflicts.

The question is how can I force (or something on the similar lines) the stash pop and edit the local files directly while avoiding the conflicts?

Comment: I'm a little too fuzzled to figure out this in detail, but I suspect you can do something with a combination of `git stash branch TEMP_BRANCH [<stash>]`, checking out your previous branch, then doing a `git cherry-pick TEMP_BRANCH` (I think) before finally deleting `TEMP_BRANCH`. (I don't entirely understand what you want in terms of overwriting/avoiding conflicts; you may want to set a merge strategy on the cherry-pick.)